# Perl - Web::Scraper - array of links

Tags: perl, web-scraping

I have this code:

```
#!/opt/local/bin/perl
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use Web::Scraper;
use Data::Dumper;

my $html = do { local $/; <DATA> };

my $br = scraper {
    process 'div#br-wrap > ul', 'bc[]' => scraper {
        process 'li > a', 'link' => '@href';
    };
};
my $res = $br->scrape( $html );
say Dumper($res);

__DATA__
<html>
<head><title>title</title></head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="br-wrap">
            <ul class="br">
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/sub/xxx">Sub-xxx</a></li>
                <li><a href="/sub/xxx/cat/name">Sub-Cat</a></li>
                <li><a href="/sub/xxx/item">Sub-Item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The result is:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'bc' => [
                    {
                      'link' => '/'
                    }
                  ]
        };
```

But, I'm looking for the **ARRAY** of links...

```
$VAR1 = {
          'bc' => [
                    {
                      'link' => '/'
                    },
                    {
                      'link' => '/sub/xxx'
                    },
                    {
                      'link' => '/sub/xxx/cat/name'
                    },
                    {
                      'link' => '/sub/xxx/item'
                    }
                  ]
        };
```

Where is the error in the code?

Comment: Care the down-voter tell me what's wrong in this question?

Comment: For all I can tell it's an example of a good question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
process 'div#br-wrap > ul > li', 'bc[]' => scraper {
    process 'a', 'link' => '@href';
```

Comment: Cool - can you please add the explanation - WHY? Asking because i want analyze the "DIV>UL" for the series of "LI > A" - so why need add the "LI" into the outer scraper? Thanx anyway!

Comment: You should actually also replace `process 'li > a'` with `process 'a'` to make the code clean. And then it make sense, right? (Answer updated)

Comment: yes, but still not understand, why my solution is not working. Thanx - will try RTFM more.. ;)

Comment: There are many **examples** in the eg/ dir packaged in distribution of `Web::Scraper`. It is recommended **to look through** these.